# Changes in the app.config, doesn't seem to affect the service after restarting

Tags: c#, windows-services, configuration-files, masstransit, topshelf

We have a service with topShelf, MassTransit/RabbitMQ, we ran the service with a wrongly configured database, after stopping the service, change the config file and restarting the service, it seems to still use the wrong connection string, if we start from the admin tools.
If we run the program as a stand-alone it works fine.

When we start the service from the admin tools it fails, if we run it separately it gets the correct value.

The service should get the updated config value after stopping and restarting, right? or do we need to uninstall the service ?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with MassTransit.

Comment: Can't you just uninstall and reinstall the service to see if it takes care of the problem?